# Does statsmodels compute R2 and other metrics on a validation-/test- set?

Tags: scikit-learn, statsmodels, goodness-of-fit, r-squared

Does statsmodels compute R2 and other metrics on a validation set?

I am using the OLS from the `statsmodels.api`
when printing summary, an r2 and r2_asjusted are presented.

I did not trust those 0.88 and computed an own adjusted R2 with scikit-learn `r2_score` and the adjusted r2 function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42392200/9447180) resulting in 0.88 as well. So the question arose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

There's [another question over on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41045752/10495893) concerning wrapping `statsmodels` models to use the `sklearn` conventions, so that you can use `sklearn` cross-validation, hyperparameter searches, etc.